# How to remotely run commands for a DB2 instance, preferably using ibm_db?

Tags: linux, db2

My objective is to see the size of Audit Buffer size, normally I would use below command on my Db2 instance

```
db2 get database manager configuration | grep AUDIT_BUF_SZ
```

But now I need to do it remotely over an Ubuntu 18 system which has my Db2 instance. For SQL query execution I used ibm_db library, an example of which is below

```
select="select * from department"
stmt_select = ibm_db.exec_immediate(ibm_db_conn, select)
cols = ibm_db.fetch_tuple( stmt_select )
print(cols[0])
```

So I need to know is there any way of getting the output of my command that can be implemented through Python, else any other library that can come in handy for this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [SYSIBMADM.DBMCFG](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022029.html)  administrative view for this.